# dart null safty issue when try to add value to map element

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I am using  Dart but i am facing null safty issue with following code

```
RxMap<Product,int>cartItems=Map<Product,int>().obs;
```

```
void updateCart(Product product,String type){
  if(type=="plus") {
    cartItems.value[product]++;
  }
  else {
    cartItems.value[product]--;
  }

}
```

i got the following error message

> the method '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

i tried to add null check to the target as following

```
cartItems.value![product]++;
```

Comment: Didn't cartItems.value![product]++; solved your problem. After that even if you got error, it should be something like "null check operator used on null value"

Answer (score 2):

You can give a default value if null.

```
cartItems.value[product]??0 +1
```

Or force assert to non null value like this.It may throw exception if element not present in HashMap

```
cartItems.value[product]!+1
```

In your question you are asserting not null for HashMap not the value of the HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `cartItems.value` is a Map and it's possible that `cartItems.value[product]` is `null`. In this case you can't add or remove `1` to `null`.
So you should do like the following:

```dart
if (type == "plus") {
  cartItems.value[product] = (cartItems.value[product] ?? 0) + 1;
} else {
  cartItems.value[product] = (cartItems.value[product] ?? 0) - 1;
}
```

Using `(cartItems.value[product] ?? 0)` you're saying that if `cartItems.value[product]` is `null` 0 is used instead.

Also note that in the else clause, when `cartItems.value[product] == null`, you're trying to remove 1 to something that doesn't exist, so in that case it may be best to throw an exception:

```
int? currentValue = cartItems.value[product];
if (currentValue == null) {
  throw Exception('Trying to remove on a null object');
}
cartItems.value[product] = currentValue - 1;
```